# "HttpCode: 400, Errormessage: request body malformed" when calling api post

Tags: android, api, kotlin, request, http-post

I am making an android application with kotlin.
I am facing the following error when calling the api.
**{"status":400,"errorMessage":"request body malformed."}**

I think the message part is the problem.

I gave the variables messages1 and messages2 values to messages, but to no avail. (RetrofitService.sendsms value was also changed to match the type)

please help me

**Here is the api guide.**

1. API Url & API Header
   [image]
2. Request body
   [image]
3. Response body
   [image]

**Next is the code I used.**

<MainActivity.kt>

```
    var messages1 = listOf(messages("0"+PhoneNum_to))
    var messages2 = """{"to": "${"0"+PhoneNum_to}"}"""
    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
    smsservice.sendsms(
        Content_Type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        timestamp = timestamp,
        accesskey = "{accesskey}",
        signature = "{signKey}",
        type = "LMS",
        contentType = "COMM",
        from = "{Caller number}",
        content = "{message content}",
        messages = messages1
)?.enqueue(object : Callback<sendsms_Response> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<sendsms_Response>, response: Response<sendsms_Response>) {
        if(response.isSuccessful){
            // true
        } else{
            // false
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<sendsms_Response>, t: Throwable) {
        // Exception
        Log.d("NaverSMSApiResult", "onFailure 에러: " + t.message.toString());
    }
})
```

<RetrofitService.kt>

```
interface RetrofitService {
    // POST 예제
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/sms/v2/services/{Service_ID}/messages")
    fun sendsms(
        @Header("Content-Type") Content_Type: String,
        @Header("x-ncp-apigw-timestamp") timestamp: String,
        @Header("x-ncp-iam-access-key") accesskey: String,
        @Header("x-ncp-apigw-signature-v2") signature: String,
        @Field("type") type: String,
        @Field("contentType") contentType: String,
        @Field("from") from: String,
        @Field("content") content: String,
        @Field("messages") messages : List<messages>
    ): Call<sendsms_Response>
}

data class messages(
    var to : String,
    var subject : String,
    var content : String,
) {
    constructor(Number : String) : this(Number, "null", "null")
}
```

<sendsms_Response.kt>

```
// DTD Create
data class sendsms_Response(
    @SerializedName("statusCode") var statusCode: String,
    @SerializedName("statusName") var statusName: String,
    @SerializedName("requestId") var requestId: String,
    @SerializedName("requestTime") var requestTime: String,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because your message data cannot be recognized as a JSON and has a problem in the body. Try to fix it in a correct JSON form and I think that will solve your problem.

also you can check out this link for more info:

https://www.ktmbytes.com/send-sms-from-android-app-using-nexmo-and-retrofit

Comment: Thank you it has been resolved.